# Weird problem in Octave: `char(97)` doesn't show result in console

Tags: windows, octave

I have no idea what's the problem of `char` in my Octave:

- I typed in console `char(97)`, which is supposed to give `"a"`, but actually nothing happened

[image]

- When I check the worksapce, I can see that there is an `"a"` there

[image]

I have no clue what's wrong with it. I am using Octave 5.2.0 in Windows 10. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this happening with `char` only?  or `char(97)` only?

Comment: @SardarUsama it happened to `char` only. It is also weird that, once this issues occurs, no matter what I typed in console, nothing will be returned. If I didn't run `char` first, then things are fine

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks! It was said in my post Octave 5.2.0 in Windows 10

Comment: You didn't happen to toggle `echo` did you? I can't imagine this is a character encoding thing.

Comment: Maybe [this is it](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?56224). Apparently, if you output a char with an ascii value greater than 127, it disables stdout. (Or https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=57133)

Comment: @beaker Thank you very much! That is it! It seems a bug with Windows...Could you move your reply as answer? I think yours if very helpful and would like to accept it. Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad that worked. I'll go ahead and type up an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an outstanding bug in Octave on Windows that causes stdout in the command window to become disabled after trying to display a character with an ASCII code greater than 127. See [bug #57133](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=57133).

This bug is currently marked as a dependency of [bug #56224](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?56224), which indicates that it only occurs in the GUI command window, and not in the CLI.